# Extract third group of text from range delimiters

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I have a **file.txt** that contains the single line:

```
[MOVING] From [/source/foo.txt] to [/dest/bar.txt]
```

I would like to find a regex that basically extract the third group inside a pair of square brackets `[]`

**expecting** `/dest/bar.txt`

So far, I came up with:

```
$> cat file.txt | grep ".*From.*to.*" | grep -oP  '(?<=to ).*$' | cut -d "[" -f 2 |  cut -d "]" -f 1
```

which works but doesn't like an elegant solution at all. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -o '\[[^]]*\]$' file.txt | sed 's/\[//; s/\]//'
```

This anchors the grep to the end of the line, then extracts the square brackets and desired text. The `sed` command strips off the brackets.

Comment: Note that this extracts the *last* group, not the *third* group. It isn't clear from the question whether this is an acceptable implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "$a"
[MOVING] From [/source/foo.txt] to [/dest/bar.txt]
$ echo "$a" |egrep -o '\[.[^ ]+\]$'
[/dest/bar.txt]
```

Comment: Note that this extracts the *last* group, not the *third* group. It isn't clear from the question whether this is an acceptable implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` to extract the part after the opening bracket you're interested in, and complete with sed to remove the part after the maching bracket.

```
cut -d '[' -f 3 | sed 's/].*//'
```

Alternatively, you can do it in a single sed or awk command.

```
sed 's/^[^[]*\[\([^\]\)]*\][^[]*\[\([^\]\)]*\][^[]*\[\([^\]\)]*\].*$/\3/'
gawk -F '(^|\\])[^[]*(\\[|$)' '{print $4}'
awk '{split($0, a, "(^|\\])[^[]*(\\[|$)"); print a[4]}'
```

In both awk commands, field 1 is empty because the first separator starts at the beginning of the string, so the third bracketed group is field 4.